# Python raw sockets not printing received data (but its being sent)

Tags: python, sockets, raw-sockets

I am sending two requests to a server, code is below:

```
import sys
import socket

s = socket.socket ( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
s.connect((sys.argv[1], 3232))
s.send('HELP\n')
print("1st\n" + s.recv(4096))
s.send('HELP\n')
print("2nd\n" + s.recv(4096))
s.close()
```

`HELP` should always return something; for example if using netcat:

```
# nc 10.x.x.x 3232

HELP
* LIST OF VALID COMMANDS:
...
```

The code I posted above will not always output `HELP` response. For example; it will only show the `recv` input rarely; sometimes never (below, the `1st` one isnt even shown):

```
# python example.py 10.x.x.x
1st
Welcome to...

2nd
* LIST OF VALID COMMANDS:
...
```

I thought that `HELP` wasn't be sent, so I opened wireshark and seen the following; so it appears to be sending properly:

```
HELP
* LIST OF VALID COMMANDS:
...

HELP
* LIST OF VALID COMMANDS:
...
```

Any ideas? I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong.

Comment: What is the value of `sys.argv[1]`?

Comment: Also, these are *not* raw sockets. This is TCP/IP.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimenting I managed to fix the code. The server, upon connection sends back data; so, on initial connection you must `s.recv()`; I did this and the application behaves as I would expect.

Modified code:

```
import sys
import socket

s = socket.socket ( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
s.connect((sys.argv[1], 3232))
print("0th\n" + s.recv(4096))
s.sendall('HELP\n')
print("1st\n" + s.recv(4096))
s.sendall('HELP\n')
print("2nd\n" + s.recv(4096))
s.close()
```

This returns the following always:

```
# python /tmp/test.py 10.x.x.x
0th
Welcome to...


1st
* LIST OF VALID COMMANDS:
...


2nd
* LIST OF VALID COMMANDS:
...
```